# In new Qt SDK, I get <QtInstallationDir>\QtSDK\QtCreator\lib\qtcreatorcdbext32\qtcreatorcdbext.dll cannot be found error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt-creator

I installed the latest Qt SDK. I see that though mine is a 32-bit Windows XP, the installation creates "qtcreatorcdbext64" directory instead of "qtcreatorcdbext32" directory. I get the

> "\QtSDK\QtCreator\lib\qtcreatorcdbext32\qtcreatorcdbext.dll"

error on launching the executable.

On renaming the "qtcreatorcdbext64" directory to "qtcreatorcdbext32", I get the

> The call to LoadLibrary(qtcreatorcdbext) failed, Win32 error 0n193
>        "%1 is not a valid Win32 application."  Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access

error. Where to get the 32-biut version of "qtcreatorcdbext.dll"? Have anyone got this error? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it is an issue with the latest QtSDK and is already reported.

Refer [QtDeveloperForum](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/12552) and [Qt JIRA](https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTSDK-1145)

Answer (score 1):

This error "....**qtcreatorcdbext.dll cannot be found**" happens because the qtcreatorcdbext32  and qtcreatorcdbext64 folders are missing from the Qt installation.

If you have an older version of Qt, e.g. Qt5.9.6, you can copy the qtcreatorcdbext32  and qtcreatorcdbext64 folders from \Tools\QtCreator\lib\ to the new \Tools\QtCreator\lib. These folders contain the missing qtcreatorcdbext.dll.
I don't get the error anymore.